# How to turn a raw DOM element in to a D3 selection?

Tags: d3.js

Scenario: I have several `svg` elements on a page, each displaying a different graph. When a graph receives a mouse click it triggers an event handler wherein `this` corresponds to the *raw* `svg` element that was clicked. When this happens, I want to select the graph's `path` element with D3 in order modify it.

I know that I could give each graph an ID and then use that to make a D3 selection, e.g.

```
function on_click( event ) {
  var path = d3.select( '#' + this.id ).select( 'path' );
  path.do_stuff...
}
```

but I wondered whether there was an equivalent of jQuery's feature of turning raw DOM elements in to a jQuery object, e.g.

```
jQuery( my_raw_dom_element ).do_stuff...
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do

```
d3.select(my_raw_dom_element);
```

Comment: D'oh! Can't believe I didn't think of trying that. Thank you :)